# How can I solve it?

Tags: calculus

A rectangular warehouse with a flat roof is to have a floor area of 9600 square feet . the interior is to be divided in to storeroom and office space by an interior wall parallel to  one pair of the sides of the building . The roof and floor areas will be 9,600 square feet for any building , but the total wall length will vary for different dimensions .For examples a 96 foot building could have a 96 foot interior wall , two 100 - foot exterior walls for a total length of 3(96) + 2(100) = 488 feet .   Area = 100 feet $\times$ 96feet = sq. feet  Total wall length = 3(96 - feet) + 2(100 - feet) = 488 feet . Find the dimensions that minimize the total amount of  wall

Comment: Let the building be $L \times W$ with the interior wall of length $L$.  What is the total length of wall in terms of $L,W?$  Use the area to eliminate one variable, take the derivative, set to zero...

Answer (score 2):

Let a,b be the dimensions of the building.
Chose a to be the length of the interior wall.
Thus ab = 9600, b = 9600/a.
The total amount of wall is 3a + 2b = 3a + 19200/a.
Use calculus to find a with the smallest wall lenght.

Comment: I brought 80 & 120 . Is it right ?